# Is the U.S. military bound by the same environmental laws as the country being occupied?

Tags: united-states, international-law, military, environmental-policy

Is the U.S. military bound by the same environmental laws as the country being occupied? Let's say that the United States is still occupying Afghanistan, to what extent does the U.S. military have to abide by the environmental laws of the country. I am not talking about individuals committing a felony against an individual of the occupied people, but rather the military as an institution or as an occupying force. Example, let's say that the U.S. military in Afghanistan wants to burn down equipment and goods containing petrochemicals and other highly toxic compounds, can the U.S. military do so even if it's against the environmental regulations of the country of Afghanistan? If they can't do so, who enforces the environmental laws, the government of Afghanistan itself or an international organization?

Comment: If there is a legit governing force/body, If the action/task is to be performed outside of the US compound, I think the military will listen to them or consult with them before acting to maintain a working relationship.

Comment: "Occupied" implies that the military is in the country uninvited. Are you only asking about that situation, or also about when the US military is in a country by agreement with that country?

Comment: Maybe cover both cases since I didn't think it would make a difference.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

No.

The U.S. military claims sovereign immunity and also has express exemptions from many (but not all) U.S. environmental laws. The local courts have no practical authority over the U.S. military forces and U.S. courts would not generally entertain a lawsuit to enforce foreign environmental laws against the U.S. military.

Usually, when U.S. forces are based in a foreign country with its voluntary permission, a Status of Forces Agreement is reached between that country and the U.S. government. The Status of Forces Agreement sometimes includes some environmental law requirements, but it rarely makes U.S. military forces fully subject to local environmental laws.

Comment: A really good example from the cold war was when U.S. put nukes on Thule Air Base. (Greenland was nuclear free zone). They did inform the Danish government, but most likely would not have accepted a no.

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me if Japan imposes some environmental restrictions, although it wouldn't surprise me if the US military there is still afforded some leeway as well.

Comment: @Panzercrisis I'm sure every resident of Okinawa has a long story they could tell on that topic ...

Comment: not an environmental issue, but also notable that in South Korea they ran over and killed two schoolgirls, were court martialled (under US military regs), and found not guilty of negligent homicide rather than facing the Korean justice system https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yangju_highway_incident

Comment: When I was in the Navy (1970s), we were technically in violation of laws/agreements with countries we visited.  It was a mutual “don’t ask; don’t tell” thing.

Answer (score 21):

#### Military occupiers aren't bound by the rules of the nation they're occupying.

So, let's look at the realpolitik of the situation of military occupations, for a moment. If someone sends an army into your country to occupy it, it's an act of war, and governed by the laws of war in international law. Once that war's over, and they've successfully occupied your nation, then there's no one in your country capable of opposing them; not only are they unbound by the laws of your nation, they're able to forcibly impose whatever laws they desire *onto* your nation.

The only things stopping them from doing whatever they wanted would be the political calculus about things like potentially inciting general rebellion through overly draconian rules, a negative reaction from the people back in their home nation, or negative reactions from peer powers.

Answer (score 12):

Sayaman's question is about military occupation which has a specific
and unambiguous legal meaning. Conventions, treaties, customary law,
and the domestic law of the occupier governs what the occupier can do
to occupied territory. The probably most famous and most long-lasting
example of a military occupation is Israel's occupation of the West
Bank, Gaza Strip, and Golan Heights.

In [Enhancing Environmental Protection During Occupation Through Human
Rights](https://www.gojil.eu/issues/101/101_article_hulme.pdf) Karen
Hume analyses international law and existing state practice and
concludes that the occupier has certain environmental responsibilities
vis-a-vis the occupied territory:

> Drawing on the examination of State practice above, the minimum core
> obligations of environmental human rights could be conceived as
> follows:
>
> 1. Ensuring a baseline level of environmental health, so as to meet
>    the needs of the population, such as adequate food and water
>    sources, and a healthy life itself;
> 2. Managing environmental risk, to ensure the collection and
>    provision of environmental risk information; and
> 3. Conserving a healthy environment in the broader, ecological
>    sense.

Essentially, the occupier must not unduly harm the environment of the
occupied territory. For example, it must not divert water resources,
dump toxic waste, or spray herbicides unless there is a pressing
military need. This is especially true if the domestic law of the
occupied territory prohibits those actions because the occupier must
respect the local laws in force in the country:

> The authority of the legitimate power having in fact passed into the
> hands of the occupant, the latter shall take all the measures in his
> power to restore, and ensure, as far as possible, public order and
> safety, **while respecting, *unless absolutely prevented*, the laws in
> force in the country**.
>
> [Hague Regulations: Article 43](https://ihl-databases.icrc.org/ihl/WebART/195-200053)

Thus, your example of the U.S. military burning petrochemicals in
Afghanistan would constitute a war crime.

Enforcement is a different matter. Perhaps an American soldier who
caused ecological damage in Afghanistan would face a
court-martial. However, if the ecological destruction was caused by a
conscious military strategy, it is hard to see what body would be able
to enforce a judgement against the U.S. military.

Answer (score 6):

#### Environmental Laws are no different from any other laws

When the US (or any other) military occupies a country, their rule overrides any existing laws of the *previous* government. They are, temporarily, the "law of the land". While it might seem that "environmental law" is somehow different and special, it isn't. A law is a law is a law.

To take an extreme example, if a country has a law outlawing non-Muslims from living there and practicing their own religion, the US military would not abide by such a law. They might, out of respect for the civilian population (if that population is itself majority Muslim), refrain from any public practice of non-Muslim religion outside the military bases, but they could certainly allow Christian, Jewish and other non-Muslim US military personnel to practice their religion publicly within the base (e.g., chapel, group services, etc.) and privately off-base. That is different from when the US military has an agreement with another country to establish a base for mutually agreed reasons - e.g., US in Saudia Arabia during the first Gulf War.

Answer (score 2):

The American Sector of Berlin was occupied by American troops for 45 years, from May 1945 until October 1990 (or maybe the occupation ended somewhat earlier during 1990? October was the time of reunification.).

German authorities actually governed the city. Except that occasionally something about the way they governed conflicted with the purposes of the occupying forces, who then overruled them.

American judicial power in the American Sector was vested in the United States Court for Berlin, whose judgeship was vacant until an odd incident in 1978. The U.S. had spent years trying to get East-Bloc countries, including Poland and East Germany, to sign a hijacking convention. After they finally succeeded, two East Germans, having learned that their plan to flee to West German had been discovered by authorities, used a desperate measure to flee before being arrested: they boarded a plane in Poland that was bound for East Berlin, and hijacked it to a destination only a couple of kilometers away in West Berlin. They didn't use an actual gun but rather a starting pistol. If they were not prosecuted, the hijacking treaty would be lost. But the local German authorities did not want to prosecute, since they supported efforts of East Germans to flee in defiance East German authorities. So the U.S. Court for Berlin became the trial venue, with an American judge and an American prosecutor and both American and German defense lawyers. One defendant walked for lack of a Miranda warning and the other was sentenced to time already served, which was about nine months. **So what does this have to do with the question?** The answer is that while the Court was in session, the occupying authorities wanted to build something that ran afoul of local zoning ordinances. The German authorities who enforced such ordinances were overruled by the occupiers. So their lawyers came up with a theory that that the U.S. Court for Berlin therefore had jurisdiction and asked it to act. Unfortunately for them, the business of the Court in the hijacking cases had just wrapped up, so the State Department then dissolved the Court and that was the end of that.

The judge, Herbert Jay Stern, wrote a book about it: *Judgment in Berlin*.

Comment: Fascinating. I ordered the book through my library.